# Condition number vs. reconstruction error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, noise, least-squares

Suppose I want to solve a simple, linear inverse problem given by $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{c}$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $M \times K$ matrix and I want to solve for $\mathbf{c}$ ($M$ = measurements, $K$ = unknowns). Generally, $\mathbf{y}$ is contamined by noise and with $M > K$, we use least squares (pseudo inverse).

A common wisdom is that the condition number describes the fidelity of the reconstruction, i.e., the higher the condition number, the better the reconstruction. So I just draw random matrices and plot the condition number versus the achieved NMSE. I would expect a rough relationship between the two. But what I see is all but correlated:

[image: condition number vs. NMSE]

I hope this scatter plot clearly shows that a low condition number does not mean low reconstruction error (and the other way round). I changed the parameters but did not have significant changes.

This is counter-intuitive and wrong. But what I am doing wrong? What are my wrong assumptions, if any?

PS: The (short&simple) MATLAB code can be found here if it helps: http://pastebin.com/dhQ5PaiS

Comment: Why is the NMSE negative?

Comment: Also, if you draw the matrices randomly (from certain distribution) the singular values concentrate around certain values that depend on the size of the matrix. I guess, that's why you don't have many samples with large condition number. The way you generate the matrices is important.

Comment: The NMSE of just the normalized MSE in dB, hence negative.

Comment: But that's not the problem. The problem is that there is no trend and no visible correlation at all. I would expect at least a slight correlation that lower condition number means lower error.

Comment: I see. However, still if you look at the plot you see that most of your matrices have condition number around 3. You can't expect much variation in the performance there. Perhaps that range of condition number is good enough for the available numerical precision. As I said, to see the effect of condition number you need to carefully draw matrices whose condition numbers cover a wider range (let's say from 1 to 1000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understood something wrong. The condition number is a proportionality factor in the error, the higher the condition number, i.e., the more singular or nearly rank deficient the system matrix $A$ is, the more the noise in $y$ gets amplified in the solution.

If thinking in terms of the SVD, when solving the system resp. constructing the pseudo-inverse you multiply with the inverses of the singular values. The existence of relatively small singular values means that the corresponding singular vectors get a rather huge factor in the pseudo-inverse.

That is, if $A=USV^T$ and $y=Ax+\varepsilon$, then 
$$
A^+y=x+\sum_{k=1}^m σ_k^{-1} v_k\,(u_k^Tε)
=x+σ_1^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^m (σ_1σ_k^{-1})\,(u_k^Tε)\, v_k
$$
and if $ε$ is normal iid, then also the $(u_k^Tε)$ are normal iid., and the largest error component is the last one with the condition number of $A$ as relative size.

---

**Update** If you construct the matrix $A$ by filling it with random numbers centered at $0$, independent and identically distributed, then with high probability $A$ will end up having columns that are of almost equal magnitude and that are close to orthogonal. This is just the law of large numbers. Such a matrix has automatically a rather small condition number.

To get "bad" matrices, construct them via the SVD. Fill $U\in\Bbb R^{N\times m}$ and $V\in\Bbb R^{m\times m}$ randomly, as before, and set $S=diag(1,q,q^2,...,q^{m-1})$ for some $q<1$. $q^{1-m}$ will then be the magnitude of the condition number of $A=USV^T$.

If desired, one can extract the "truly" orthogonal content of the randomly generated $U$ and $V$ by performing QR decompositions and replacing them with the Q factor.

Comment: Thanks, I see that. But this does still not explain the plot. I don't care about the exact relation between error and condition number but it definitely should have a correlation, right? So on average, I should be able to say: The lower the condition number, the lower the error (e.g., based on your arguments). Why is this not visible in the experimental plots? Or stated differently: How would you experimentally show condition number vs. error?

Comment: One more comment: I hope you agree that in the end, all we really care is the error. The condition number is just a proxy. So if the condition number is independent of the error, and the error is "arbitrary" anyway, why should I care getting a low condition number?

Comment: The diagram is really not representative. Condition numbers below 10 indicate extremely well-behaved matrices. High condition numbers start with 100, sometimes even 1000 is not considered ill-conditioned. To get such a matrix with $n$ long columns, one could generate $n-3$ columns randomly first, and then fill the remaining $3$ columns with linear combinations (random coefficients with absolute sum about $1$) of the other columns plus some small noise. The size of the noise is approximately inverse to the condition number, zero noise gives infinity ill-condition.

Comment: Thanks for the update!That sounds really promising. But are you sure this works out (or do I misinterpret "magnitude")? With m=6, q=0.5, q^(1-m) is always 32. But if I use cond(A), the number has still a high variance (between 70 and 1500). Which makes sense because if I do an SVD on A, the singular values are different from the ones in "S" because they are inconsistent with the singular vectors in U and V. Or do you mean that "q^(1-m)" is a "very rough" lower bound?

Comment: Apart from that, this works out now, but it makes only sense on a logarithmic scale. The correlation is visible (I also draw "q" from a uniform distibution). This suggests to me that it does not make sense to care about/optimize the condition number if I do not expect variances more than one order of magnitude in my condition numbers. Is that right?

Comment: Well, it is still a random matrix, so the orthogonality is not perfect, and the more aligned the columns are, the greater the condition number. But the goal of significantly larger condition numbers was reached, so no further optimizations are necessary for the numerical experiment. -- Is your last remark still about the experiment or about its conclusions? I'd say yes, one order of magnitude (if that means a factor of 10, a factor of 100 or 1000 would be different) is not important enough.